# OptaPlanner - restricting matches to x amount

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm rather new to OptaPlanner, and Java in general - but hopefully this makes sense.  What I'm trying to do is match, lets say, `Client`, to an `Associate` - what I'm looking to do is ensure that said `Associate` can only have X amount of clients assigned to them.  My domain is pretty simple right now, in that it is just the `Associate` and the `ClientAssignment` (which contains all of the client information) along with the planning solution/constraints to map them together.

**Question**:
How can I infer what has already been 'matched', to get a count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're using the [Constraint Streams API](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreams) to implement your scoring function. If so, the following code should give you an idea of how to achieve what you need:

```
.from(ClientAssignment.class)
.groupBy(ClientAssignment::getAssociate, 
    ConstraintCollectors.count())
.filter((associate, assignmentCount) -> assignmentCount > MAX_ALLOWED_CLIENT_COUNT)
.penalize("Overloaded associate", 
    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, 
    (associate, assignmentCount) -> assignmentCount - MAX_ALLOWED_CLIENT_COUNT)
```

Obviously, I've made some assumptions about how your data model looks. Specifically, I've assumed that `ClientAssignment` is a unique pair of one `Client` and one `Associate`. If that assumption is not correct, please be more specific in your question and I'll edit my answer.

Also, you should replace `HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD` by whatever penalty you see applying to your problem, in whatever `Score` type that you need.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling groupBy was what I was looking for - will give that a shot! :)

Regarding the data model, I think you have it understood - I'm trying to keep it simple for my purpose, should just be a 1:1 mapping ultimately.  Is the ConstraintCollectors a built in thing? Again, sorry - pretty new to this app

Comment: Yes, the ConstraintCollectors class is a standard part of the API. Has plenty of useful collector implementations out of the box, check out the docs or IDE code completion.

Comment: Didn't get a chance to implement this until today, but works a treat - thanks again!